# What is the purpose of github authentication in composer-rest-server?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

If I set up composer-rest-server to use github authentication (as described in https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/enabling-rest-authentication.html), then a client of the rest server needs to authenticate against github. 
If this authentication is successful, then the client acts with the business card that was specified during startup of the rest server (or with the one that was uploaded in multi-user mode).

However, ANY github user may authenticate that way! There is no control which github users may use the rest server (I would expect a configuration file with a white list etc.). Therefore ANY github user may interact with the blockchain the same way using the business card of the rest server?!

This is quite useless in my opinion. Or do I oversee something? What is the purpose of github authentication in composer-rest-server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before authentication there is no real access to the Business Network, after authentication there is access to add Cards to a Wallet after which there is access to the business network (controlled by ACL).

The Wallet is unique to the authenticated user, so in your github example if you open a different browser and use a different Github ID you will have an empty Wallet, and no access to the network - except to add a card.

With regard to Github it is just used as an example of a Passport Strategy for Authentication - it is used in the example docs as it is quite easy to set up and anybody can use Github.  It might be useful for a public blockchain, but for many examples it might be more appropriate to use a Passport Strategy to connect to a private LDAP or Active Directory.

Comment: "The Wallet is unique to the authenticated user" is true only for multiuser mode, isn't it?

Comment: Yes.  There is a possible use case for using Authentication in single user (i.e. everybody having access via the card that started the REST Server)  - the card that starts the rest server does not have to be an 'Admin', it could be a card that has access limited by ACL so it sees only certain Assets and perhaps only a subset of them - then that instance of the REST server could be used as a simple non-confidential enquiries e.g. is a Car legally Insured or not?